# How can I setup Apache Archiva as cache fo all my maven projects?

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, archiva

I have setup Apache Archiva with internal repo at

http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/

But when I trying to run "mvn compile",requests for artifacts are forwarded to Apache Archiva but I see following error:

Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-build:pom:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 13, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Do I need to update any specific settings so Archiva can fetch required artifact from remote repository?

Content from ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal</id>
      <name>Internal repo + cache </name>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles>
      <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>internal</id>
              <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
              <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
              <id>snapshots</id>
              <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
              <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Comment: How have you told Maven that it should use Archiva?  You want a mirror configuration.

Comment: I have added my maven settings .

Comment: If you can figure this out please post the answer.  I've been trying to figure this out for almost two months.  No one on Stack seems to really know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know archiva comes with the default configuration to search artifacts in maven central repo. As maven central does not contain SNAPSHOT versions of artifacts, you cannot fetch it from there.

Try to address a release version instead of SNAPSHOT.

Comment: I am facing same issue for release version :   Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.apache.apex:apex:pom:3.4.0 in internal (http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 25, column 11 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Can you post your settings.xml ? Or do you have already change repository settings in settings.xml as described here: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/userguide/using-repository.html

Comment: I have pasted settings xml in original question

Comment: It seems correct to me. Do you tried to search any artifacts using archiva instance on your local machine?

Comment: Yes but no results were found. It should search in local repository or central repo?

Comment: Do you have local proxy configuration?